# Get data from Json bracket into AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get some specific data froma JSON object.

I am able to get the data from outside the brackets, but can't get anything from inside them.

What I'd like to get is get the `"summonerName"` from below.

```
  "gameId": 2016761444,
  "mapId": 11,
  "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
  "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
  "gameQueueConfigId": 4,
  "participants": [
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 4,
      "spell2Id": 12,
      "championId": 57,
      "profileIconId": 615,
      "summonerName": "Wolves Weekend",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 22951400,
      ]
    },
```

There are 9 more 'participants' objects.

And this is how I'm trying to do it currently:

```
div(ng-repeat='data in info.display')
            p(ng-model='info.IdBox') {{data.id}}
            p Level: {{data.summonerLevel}}
            p Champion: {{data.championId}}
            {{info.matchInfo}}
    ul
        div(ng-repeat='participant in info.matchInfo')
            p Name: {{matchInfo.participants[participant].summonerName}}
```

As said before, simple calls are working fine...

Any idea?

Thank you~

Comment: What is the value of `participant`? `participants` is an array you need to address them by index `0, 1, 2, etc...`, my guess is `participant` is not a number.

Comment: Your brackets (in your JSON) are mismatched. Is participants an array or an object?

Comment: What is `info`? Post complete JSON.

Comment: What's inside `info.matchInfo`, is it the `JSON` your posted or just the `participants` array?

Comment: Yep, it's the json I posted. It's croped because it's repeated 9 more times like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your JSON is invalid inside the `participants` object.

Example of your JSON right now:

```
  "participants": [
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 4,
      "spell2Id": 12,
      "championId": 57,
      "profileIconId": 615,
      "summonerName": "Wolves Weekend",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 22951400, //Extra semicolon and missing curly brace.
      ]
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
{
    "gameId": 2016761444,
    "mapId": 11,
    "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
    "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "gameQueueConfigId": 4,
    "participants": [
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 12,
            "championId": 57,
            "profileIconId": 615,
            "summonerName": "Wolves Weekend",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": 22951400
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice you have what you wish to retrieve inside an object that holds an array. You need to identify the item in the array you wish to read from in order to then specify the key you which to read.

All you need to do is access that child object inside the array. You do this by providing the `index` of the item in the array you are accessing.

```
var jsonObject = 'yourJsonDataWouldBeHere...';
var mySelectedField = jsonObject.participants[1].summonerId;
```

**Example of your current code running:**

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

  $scope.jsonData = {
    "gameId": 2016761444,
    "mapId": 11,
    "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
    "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "gameQueueConfigId": 4,
    "participants": [
           {
                "teamId": 100,
                "spell1Id": 4,
                "spell2Id": 12,
                "championId": 57,
                "profileIconId": 615,
                "summonerName": "Wolves Weekend",
                "bot": false,
                "summonerId": 22951400
            },
         {
                "teamId": 101,
                "spell1Id": 5,
                "spell2Id": 13,
                "championId": 58,
                "profileIconId": 616,
                "summonerName": "Bear Something",
                "bot": false,
                "summonerId": 22951400
            }
    ]
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    
    <!--I'm accessing the ARRAY directly...-->
    <ul ng-repeat="item in jsonData.participants">
      <li>{{item.summonerName}}</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Your example was perfect, thank you very much!